# How to modify the content and create many instances for a dynamic user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to use a User Control many times in the same page.aspx

I am working with visual studio 2012 and asp.net 4.0 I trying to do many graph that receives different parameter each one.

I have an user control.ascx that has code behind control.ascx.cs with a function

```
public void myTask(string myParameter)
```

I have a page.aspx with a panel

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
```

I had a code behind page.aspx.cs with

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl cuc = (UserControl)LoadControl("~/cmmon/userCntrol/myusercontrol.ascx");
    Panel1.Controls.Add(cuc);
```

My code shows nice for just one graphic.

I am willing to create many instances for my user Control and call each function from the page.aspx int the behind code page.aspx.cs like

```
myTask(myParameter);
```

with different parameter for each one. How do I do?

Comment: It can be done in many ways : programatically with loop, or with Repeater control ... where is the problem?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Problem is modify the content because each graph should be different with different data and I don't know how to identify each graph to assign different values.  I am willing to call a function with a different parameter in a different instance. Ex one graph can said myTask("Euro") other can be myTask("Dolar") or myTask("Pesos").  I do not know how to identify and create each instance.

Comment: We also don't know this as you didn't mention about source of data obvious code is  `foreach(var data : datas) { CreateControlAndAddToParent().CastToMyControl().myTask(data); }`

Comment: Difficult is: this is a user control not an asp:object. I can't include the control class in the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple in a loop. Make sure to give each an unique ID.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    WebUserControl1 cuc = (WebUserControl1)LoadControl("~/WebUserControl1.ascx");
    cuc.ID = "Control" + i;
    Panel1.Controls.Add(cuc);
}
```

Then you can locate the control somewhere else in the code based on that ID.

```
WebUserControl1 uc = Panel1.FindControl("Control3") as WebUserControl1;
```

Comment: Hi VDWWD. The code works good when all the code is in one file, using <script> in aspx file.  If you create a aspx.cs file no works. it give me this error: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyControl' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I found it! Thank you so much.<%@ Reference Control="~/cmmon/userCntrol/myusercontrol.ascx" %>

Answer (score 0):

I found and resolve two issues: 1) how to send parameters to a control object. and 2) how to reference a control in another c# page.

1) To send parameters to a control object I have to define variables to accept the values of the parameters, it is done in the object control by:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
public partial class myControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string variable { get; set; }
    public void start(string parameter)
    {
        variable = parameter;
    }
}
```

2) To reference a control in another c# page. in the page directive should be:

```
<%@ Reference Control="~/cmmon/userCntrol/myControl.ascx" %>
```

Then, as VDWWD answer, in your code behind you can include an object like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    WebUserControl1 cuc = (WebUserControl1)LoadControl("~/WebUserControl1.ascx");
    cuc.ID = "Control" + i;
    Panel1.Controls.Add(cuc);
}
```

And call the function as I needed:

```
cuc.myTask(myParameter);
```

Then:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    WebUserControl1 cuc = (WebUserControl1)LoadControl("~/WebUserControl1.ascx");
    cuc.ID = "Control" + i;
    Panel1.Controls.Add(cuc);
    cuc.myTask(myParameter);
}
```